# How to check date format if it have different input like 'yyyy-mm-dd' or 'yyyymmdd'?

Tags: python

i have question how to check date input?

Here's some algorithm that i make

```
#The input
Enter the date: yyyy-mm-dd #The format is string
or
Enter the date: yyyymmdd


if the input like yyyy-mm-dd:
   print(yyyy-mm-dd)
else if the input like yyyymmdd:
   print(yyyy-mm-dd)
else: #If the input have alphabet
   print ("Sorry, wrong format bro!")
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Worth learning [regular expressions](https://realpython.com/regex-python/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ensures a valid date format goes through. The regex solution will allow in stuff like 2020-99-99.

```
import datetime

date = "2020-02-01"

def format_check(date, fmt):
    try: datetime.datetime.strptime(date, fmt)
    except: return False
    else: return True
    
if not format_check(date, '%Y-%m-%d') and not format_check(date, '%Y%m%d'):
    raise ValueError("Sorry, wrong format bro!")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use regular expression  like re'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'  in here we want exactly 4 number and 2 then another 2 for days and month then 4 digit for year